# Make paths in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i have spring boot project in which i need to create Spring boot applications related with students.
In 1st i have to make send students on localhost:8080/students
- and it works well for me 
In 2nd i have to send students by their index on localhost:8080/students/index 
- and it works well also
In 3rd i have to send students by their studyProgram on localhost:8080/students/studyProgram and there is the problem studyProgram is OBJECT so i cannot reference it and i tried some different ways, so i ask for a help

**My StudentDao,** place where the database of students ARE

```
    @Repository
    public class StudentDao {

        private static Map<String,Student>students;
        private static Map<Integer,StudyProgram>programs;
        static
        {
            programs = new HashMap<Integer, StudyProgram>()
            {
                {
                    put(1,new StudyProgram((long)41,"kni"));
                    put(2,new StudyProgram((long)42,"pet"));
                    put(3,new StudyProgram((long)43,"info"));
                    put(4,new StudyProgram((long)44,"iki"));
                }
            };
        }

        static
        {
            students = new HashMap<String, Student>()
            {
                {
                    put("141333", new Student("141333","asd","fgh",programs.get(1)));
                    put("14111", new Student("14111","Trajko","Trajkov",programs.get(2)));
                    put("140000", new Student("140000","Petko","Petkov",programs.get(3)));
                    put("145555", new Student("145555","Mile","Milev",programs.get(4)));
                }
            };
        }

        public Collection<Student> getAllStudents()
        {
            return this.students.values();
        }

        public Student getStudentByIndex(String index){
            return this.students.get(index);
        }
        /* THIS HERE MAKES THE PROBLEM

        public Student getStudentByStudyProgram(Student st){
            return this.students.get(st.getStudyProgramId());
        }
        */

}
```

**My StudentService**

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;
    private StudyProgram studyProgram;
    public Collection<Student> getAllStudents()
    {
        return this.studentDao.getAllStudents();
    }

    public Student getStudentByIndex(String index){
        return this.studentDao.getStudentByIndex(index);
    }

    /* THIS HERE MAKES PROBLEM
    public Student getStudentByStudyProgram(Student st){
        return this.studentDao.getStudentByStudyProgram(st);
    }

    */

}
```

**My StudentController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Student>getAllStudents()
    {
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

    //4.1 Get Students by index 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{index}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Student getStudentByIndex(@PathVariable ("index") String index)
    {
        return this.studentService.getStudentByIndex(index);
    }
    /* AND THIS HERE ALSO
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{studyProgram}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Student getStudentByStudyProgram(@PathVariable ("studyProgram") Student st)
    {
        return this.studentService.getStudentByStudyProgram(st);
    }
    */

}
```

**Student class**

```
public class Student {

    String index; //primary key
    String name;
    String lastname;
    //ovde treba studyProgram na kraj
    StudyProgram studyProgram;

    public Student(String index, String name, String lastname, StudyProgram studyProgram)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.studyProgram = studyProgram;
    }
    Student(){}
WITH ALL METHODS IMPLEMENTED HERE

}
```

**And finnally my StudyProgram class**

```
public class StudyProgram {
    Long programId;
    String name;

    public StudyProgram(Long programId, String name)
    {
        this.programId = programId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    StudyProgram(){}

}
```

So finnally i want to ask can you help me to map make a map on localhost:8080/students/studyProgram and map them by their study program

In the fields commented there is where it needs to be fixed

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you create an endpoint that gives you students by Study program index, or study program name?

Comment: @SaWo thats my question i don't know how to create the endpoint to give me my students by Study program id, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is, how to create the endpoint to retrieve your students by Study program id

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{studyProgramId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Student getStudentByStudyProgram(@PathVariable ("studyProgramId") Long studyProgramId)
{
    return this.studentService.getStudentByStudyProgramId(studyProgramId);
}
```

The only thing to need to do is, implement the **getStudentByStudyProgramId** method, and it should work.